# Compare variables with leading zero in perl

Tags: perl, variables, compiler-errors, compare

I'm trying to compare the first 7 characters in $num1 and $num2. When i compile it i get a weird output. The output doesn't match $num1 or $num2. How can i compare these 2 variables?

> OUTPUT: num1[2739073] num2[2739074]

```
$num1 = 012345601;
$num2 = 012345602;

#$num1 =~ s/^0+//;
#$num2 =~ s/^0+//;

if (substr($num1, 0, -2) == substr($num2, 0, -2)) {
    print "num1[$num1]" . " num2[$num2]\n";
} else {
    print "Not equal\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue #1:

In Perl you compare strings with the [`eq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) operator, not `==`:

A correct comparison would be:

```
if ( substr($num1, 0, 7) eq substr($num2, 0, 7) ) {
    # ...
}
else {
    # ...
}
```

Issue #2:

Numbers that start with 0 in are interpreted as *octal*, you can read more about this in [`perldoc perlnumber`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html)

```
12345601 (octal) == 2739073 (decimal)
12345602 (octal) == 2739074 (decimal)
```

Issue #3:

Missing `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the problem is that

```
my $num1 = 012345601;  # Assigns 2739073 (octal 012345601)
my $num2 = 012345602;  # Assigns 2739074 (octal 012345601)
```

should be

```
my $num1 = '012345601';
my $num2 = '012345602';
```

---

A simple way of comparing all but the last two digits is

```
int($num1/100) == int($num2/100)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start your numbers with a zero, then Perl interprets them as **octal** numbers (8-based), not 10-based "regular" numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to treat the numbers as strings, so:

```
$num1 = "012345601";
$num2 = "012345602";

...
```

etc.

and do use the eq instead of == at least until you want to treat the strings as numbers again.